# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: magento2, javascript, error, cache

I have encountered a weird error, after some time of development and clearing cache I am getting the following error.

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I have created several modules and start getting this error, after clearing cache.

The line where error is occurred.

```
            setText(el, "'"
    .addAttribute('translate', {
        binding: 'i18n'
    });
```

Also this error occurs in other files.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: You,need to correct ypur code wth `setText(el, "'"
    .addAttribute('translate', {
        binding: 'i18n'
    });` share full console log and file path, also try this command `php -dmemory_limit=5G setup:static:deploy { add your local code here like 'nl_NL' } -f`

Answer (score 2):

Try to set Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> JavaScript Settings -> Translation Strategy option to value "Dictionary (Translation on Storefront side)"

..or use that query:

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'dictionary' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'dev/js/translate_strategy' LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Along this line, when locked out of the admin menu due to this javascript syntax error, I found that this also works: `php bin/magento config:set dev/js/translate_strategy dictionary`, which does the same thing.

Comment: I did this along with turning off (`0`) javascript configs : `dev/js/merge_files dev/js/enable_js_bundling dev/js/minify_files dev/js/move_script_to_bottom`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
setText(el, "'"
    .addAttribute('translate', {
        binding: 'i18n'
    }));
```

You have not closed ')' while you have opened 2 '(' and closed 1. Please check your code.

Comment: I haven't modify any JS file, this error appeared instantly, there more files that have that problem and I didn't touch them

Comment: Did you any extension recently?

Comment: I have disabled all custom modules, but still have the same issue